# JSON Object Data inserted into SQL Server table

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying grab the JSON object head for each currency and insert it into a SQL Server table.

This is the code I am using, however I get null values:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
   "currency": {
    "0": {
      "ISOCode": "USD",
      "name": "US Dollar",
      "symbol": "$",
      "real": "$#,###.##",
      "free": "#,###.##"
    },
    "1": {
      "ISOCode": "IEP",
      "name": "Irish Pound or Punt",
      "symbol": "£",
      "real": "£#,###.##",
      "free": "#,###.##"
    },
    "2": {
      "ISOCode": "BEF",
      "name": "Belgian Franc",
      "symbol": "₣",
      "real": "#,###.##₣",
      "free": "#,###.##"
     }
   }
}'

SELECT j2.* 
INTO #TempCurrencyTable
FROm OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    currency INT
) j2

SELECT * 
FROM #TempCurrencyTable
```

I get a null value and can't seem to get the header values.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `header`? JSON has no headers or columns, only arrays and dictionaries. The string you posted has a `Currency` dictionary with elements strangely named `0`, `1` etc. Each of those elements is a dictionary with its own attributes. Nothing forces those dictionaries to have the same attributes as the others

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apologies - possibly using the wrong terminology , I need to grab the "0" , "1" and "2" values and insert them into a data table.

Comment: It's not a matter of terminology. If you expect a "header" when there's none, you'll get nothing.  "0" and "1" are the keys of the `currency` dictionary and appear in `j1.key`. The `j1.value` column contains the inner objects, which have no `currency` attribute. You can write just `SELECT j1.key
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1` to get the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

What you need here is the next statement:

```
SELECT 
   j1.[key],
   j2.* 
INTO #TempCurrencyTable
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    ISOCode NVARCHAR(10),
    name NVARCHAR(50),
    symbol NVARCHAR(50)
) j2
```

**Explanations:**

When you use `... OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1 ...` you execute `OPENJSON()` with default schema and the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. When you use `... OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH ( .. ) ..` you execute `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema and the result is a table with columns defined in your schema.

The documentation about `OPENSON()` return value is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value).

Answer (score 2):

A JSON string contains only arrays and objects (dictionaries). It has no header. This JSON string contains a top-level object/dictionary with a single element with key value `currency`. That element is a dictionary with key values "0", "1" etc. Each of those elements contains another boject . Nothing forces those elements to have the same keys

`OPENJSON` returns the key/value elements of a JSON dictionary as `key` and `value` columns. This means that the currency keys will appear in the `key` column. The `value` column will hold the inner dictionary.

`WITH` can be used to parse the value and extract specific attributes as columns. It can't be used to parse the key

This query :

```
SELECT *
FROm OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1
```

Returns :

```
key value                       type
0   { "ISOCode": "USD",  ... }  5
1   { "ISOCode": "IEP",  ... }  5
2   { "ISOCode": "BEF",   ... } 5
```

Keys are always strings. To convert the key to an integer a `CASR` or `PARSE` is needed :

```
SELECT cast([key] as int)
FROm OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1
```

The second OPENJSON can be used to parse the currency objects. Without `WITH`, a new row will be returned for every attribute. `WITH` can be used to expose the properties as columns. This query :

```
SELECT 
    cast(j1.[key] as int) ID,
    j2.*
FROm OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value])  
        with (  ISOCode nvarchar(3), 
                [name] nvarchar(30),
                symbol nvarchar(3),
                [real] nvarchar(10),
                free nvarchar(10)) j2
```

Returns :

```
ID  ISOCode name                symbol  real        free
0   USD     US Dollar           $       $#,###.##   #,###.##
1   IEP     Irish Pound or Punt £       £#,###.##   #,###.##
2   BEF     Belgian Franc       ₣       #,###.##₣   #,###.##
```